# Cron job stopped running

Tags: cron, ubuntu-mate

This cron job has stopped working.
It last ran on Sep. 27.

```
# Empty trash every 120 minutes
*/120 * * * * /home/andy/bin/emptytrash60.sh
```

Content of `emptytrash120.sh`:

```
Trash_Log=/home/andy/Downloads/Trash_log.txt

trash-empty

date +"%m-%d-%Y-%I:%M" >> $Trash_Log
echo "Trash has been emptied." >> $Trash_Log
#rm $Trash_Log
```

How do I diagnose what is going on?

Output of `stat /home/andy/bin/emptytrash120.sh`:

```
  File: /home/andy/bin/emptytrash120.sh 
  Size: 250 Blocks: 8 IO Block: 4096 regular file 
Device: 801h/2049d Inode: 772 Links: 1 
Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x) Uid: ( 1000/ andy) Gid: ( 1000/ andy) 
Access: 2022-09-29 05:28:30.191747869 -0500 
Modify: 2022-09-29 05:28:24.303820397 -0500 
Change: 2022-09-29 05:28:24.351819806 -0500 
 Birth: -
```

Comment: I'm not completely certain, therefore only as a comment: I wouldn't be surprised if cron balks at the "120" value. The "minutes" field is to my knowledge defined as 0-59. You may want to check whether something like `0 2 * * *` works better for you ("every two hours at 00 minutes").

Comment: I think you mean `0 */2 * * *` - see my answer.

Comment: Also please list the output of: `stat /home/andy/bin/emptytrash60.sh`

Comment: So you changed the name of the file? Maybe you should run the correct file as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since you obviously changed the name of the file, try the following setting in crontab:

```
# Empty trash every 2 hours
0 */2 * * * /home/andy/bin/emptytrash120.sh
```

This syntax should be more feasible for cron.

Comment: I will try your suggestion. @Artur Meinild